# Display posts with author in the url with custom post types

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, author, slug

I'm having a really difficult time with this.
I have a multi-user gallery site. Each author has his own page that lists the author's posts (this is a custom post type).

I have made it so that the author url(author.php) is www.example.com/firstname-lastname/. 
But when a visitor clicks on one of the author's posts, the url changes to www.example.com/custom-post-type-name/postname/ while I want it to be www.example.com/firstname-lastname/postname/. How do I achieve this? With .htaccess? Or changing the rewrite rule when registering the post type? How?

I use this to register my post type in functions.php file:

```
// Make custom post type Add media

function galleryRegister()
{
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Add gallery', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Add gallery', 'post type singular name'),
);

$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => null,
'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
'rewrite' => false,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
);

register_post_type('gallery' , $args);
}

add_action('init', 'galleryRegister');
```

Thanks for help.

Edit: I found out that I can manually type www.example.com/firstname-lastname/postname/ and it shows the correct post, but the permalink is still same old
www.example.com/custom-post-type-name/postname/ everywhere

**Solution:**
Thank you Stephen for the great answer! This is the code that I used and it worked:

```
// ****************************************************
// Make a custom post type "Add gallery"
// ****************************************************
function galleryRegister()
{
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Add gallery', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Add gallery', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add gallery ', 'portfolio item'),
'all_items' => __( 'Manage your galleries' ),
'add_new_item' => __('Add gallery'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit your galleries'),
'new_item' => __('New gallery'),
'view_item' => __('View gallery on site'),
'search_items' => __('Search galleries'),
'not_found' => __('Nothing found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => null,
'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
'rewrite' =>  array( 'slug' => _x( '%author%', 'URL slug') ),
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
);

register_post_type('gallery' , $args);
}

add_action('init', 'galleryRegister');

// ****************************************************
// Flush rewrite rules. Delete this 
// ****************************************************
function my_rewrite_flush() {
    my_cpt_init();

    // ATTENTION: This is *only* done during plugin activation hook in this example!
    // You should *NEVER EVER* do this on every page load!!
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_rewrite_flush' );

// ****************************************************
// Make author as slug for posts
// ****************************************************
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse73228_author_tag',10,4);
function wpse73228_author_tag($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample){

    if( 'gallery' != get_post_type($post) )
        return $post_link;

    $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$author = $authordata->user_nicename;

$post_link = str_replace('%author%', $author, $post_link);

return $post_link;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `%author%` tag in the `rewrite` property in `register_post_type()`. However, although the rewrite rules are added (after they're flushed) - WordPress doesn't replace the tag with its appropriate value when generating the permalink of your post type. For instance you end up with the permalink *www.example.com/%author%/gallery-name*

The following replaces `%author%` with the appropriate value:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse73228_author_tag',10,4);
function wpse73228_author_tag($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample){

    if( 'gallery' != get_post_type($post) )
        return $post_link;

    $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $author = $authordata->user_nicename;

    $post_link = str_replace('%author%', $author, $post_link);

    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: This worked well for my CPTs, but now clicking any of my non-CPTs results in a 404! I posted more details at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124253/28957 and would appreciate if anyone has any guidance.

Comment: @cfx, did you find a solution to your 404 problem? I'm having the same issue: after adding the above mentioned solution to customize my custom post type permalink with the author instead of the post type name, now all of my pages return 404. The only thing that works is the custom post type.